# error in migration of zf2 to zf3. unable to resolve services,

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am migrating an application from from zf2 to zf3.

all is good but on a page which is using "viewhelpermanager", through an error.

error : `"Unable to resolve service "viewhelpermanager" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?"`.

I have checked there is an service  configuration for `"viewhelpermanager"` in Zf2. but could not found in ZF3.

it is working in zf2, but not in zf3.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per zend Docs.
"In v3, service names are case sensitive, and are not normalized in any way."

and in your case, In zf2 there was "viewhelpermanager" as well as "ViewHelperManager", now in Zf3, only "ViewHelperManager" available.

but in Zf3 add below line into your Module.php.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'aliases' => array(
                'viewhelpermanager' =>'ViewHelperManager'
             )
        );
    }
```

If `getServiceConfig()` exists just add

```
 'aliases' => array(
                    'viewhelpermanager' =>'ViewHelperManager'
                 )
```

for more infomation and details, please see [migration guide Zf2 to Zf3](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/migration/)